# In GWT is the 2.5 interface RpcService replaced by RemoteService interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm currently going through the book *GWT in Action 2nd Edition* and its example code. In chapter 5 under the discussions on `ClientBundle` usage they have example code where there is an interface that extends `com.google.gwt.rpc.client.RpcService`. When I loaded this example project into my Eclipse IDE, the code shows red as the package `com.google.gwt.rpc` does not exist. This is most likely because I'm using GWT 2.7 and the book was written back in GWT 2.5. I attempted to look into the JavaDoc to see when it was removed, and what its replacement should be, but the only JavaDoc is for the latest, and downloads for 2.5 from the website returns no page found (404) errors. My IDE is suggesting that I change the requested interface to `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService` but without knowing if this is the correct replacement, it seems a bit odd.

The code example they provide is as follows:

```
package com.manning.gwtia.ch05.client.cssresource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.rpc.client.RpcService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("CSSResourceService")
public interface ResourceService extends RpcService {
    List<String> getThemes();
    HashMap<String, String> getTheme(String name);
}
```

Does anyone know what the proper replacement interface for `RpcService` and maybe also tell me in which version it was removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.google.gwt.rpc` was an **experiment** aimed at replacing RPC from `com.google.gwt.user`. It didn't met expectations and was ultimately removed in 2.7. So yes, use `RemoteService`, like you should have actually always done.

Comment: Thanks, the book didn't explain why they used that interface, and of course it's old enough to have lost this bit of information.